# Check the machine is accessible or not using command

Tags: command-line, batch-file, command

I have batch file in which i am restarting a machine and  want to check if machine is back online then execute the code block else after particular time inform the user the machine is not online
I want to check something like:

```
pingresult = ping \\machinename

if (pingresult == true)
{
  execute some task
}
else
{
   keep  pinging for say 5min. if after 5mins machine is not up show message to user
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will try pinging %machinename% for 100 times with a default timeout of 3 seconds: 3s * 100 = 300s, i.e. 5 minutes.

```
for /L %%N IN (1, 1, 100) DO (
    ping -n 1 %machinename%
    if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (
        set pingresult=true
        goto done
    )
)
set pingresult=false
:done
if %pingresult% == true (
  echo "ping ok, doing something..."
) else (
  echo "no reply after 5 mins, error!"
)
```

Comment: You should not have \\ before the machine name - that won't work the way you think it will.

Comment: @Mark right, I replaced \\machinename with %machinename% to make it clear this is just a placeholder for the name of the remote host. An IP address would be fine, too.

Comment: As I am passing \\machinename to batch file as argument,so I used  SET test=%1, SET result=%test:*\\=% , ping -n 1 %result%.
It worked.. Thanks for the solution